# Calculating car engine RPM from inputs

Tags: classical-mechanics, heat-engine

So I am willing to calculate engine RPM of car. The usual process for doing this in games is:

$\omega_\mathrm{e} = \omega_\mathrm{w} * D_\mathrm{k} * g_\mathrm{k} * 60 / 2\pi$

However, this seems to not to be the most realistic method, it doesn't assume such things as clutch etc. So I wanna know how can I calculate engine RPM in more realistic way. This is for a game. My aviable inputs so far are:

- Torque curve
  [image: Torque curve]
- Clutch ( a float value between 0 and 1 matching how much the clutch pedal is pressed )
- Throttle ( just like clutch )
- Such things like $\delta t$ and other stuff provided by game engine

Comment: Engine rpm is not calculatable from other things, but known at each point. For a particular engine rpm and throttle position engine torque _is calculated_. Engine rpm is carried from the previous simulation step, and then changed according to the net torque applied on the crankshaft (engine torque - driveline torque).

Comment: I know that I calculate it from previous data, but how to do it in particulary phyiscly accurate way and by taking in things like clutch?

Comment: The clutch is a constraint, supplying as much driveline torque as needed to match the engine rpm to the transmission input shaft. You want to build a 1D driveline model of a car (engine, clutch, transmission, differential and tire). As I said the rpm is integrated with $$ \frac{{\rm d}\omega}{{\rm d}t} = I^{-1}  T_{net}(\omega) $$ at each step.

Comment: @ja72 And what is the $I$?

Comment: Mass [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) of the engine rotating parts.

Comment: I have no idea how to obtain them. Also, I don't understand why the $\omega$ is in brackets.

Comment: It is not brackets, but a parenthesis to show the torque $T_{net}$ is a function of engine speed.

Comment: Hm... And what type of function is it? What does it have in it?

Comment: Use $$ I \approx I_{crank} + R^2 \left(  \frac{5}{6} - \frac{R^2}{12 L^2} \right) m_{rod} + R^2 \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{R^2}{4 L^2} \right) m_{piston} $$ where $R$ is the crank radius (half stroke), $L$ the connecting rod length (rod mass is $m_{rod}$) and piston mass is $m_{piston}$.

Comment: You have the chart that shows the torque as a function of engine speed. It is not an _analytical_ function.

Comment: The problem with is posting is that it is too broad really. What you are asking for is rather complex and your understanding is not there yet.

Comment: jay72, if you could write a material about this with explanations and details, I would be really happy about that:) And yes, I don't understand some of the things there yet.

Comment: This is not the right forum for a lecture in vehicle performance simulation.

Comment: Would you like to have a little talk on mail? My e-mail is adris3ddev@gmail.com if you are interested to help a bit. I know that this place isn't the right one for a lots of material.